# ProcessBuilder not updating the record on a particular object

Tags: lightning, community, process-builder

Hi I have requirement as Process builder to copy the fields from contact object to Case object on the basis of a check box and contact look up fields.

The process builder is working perfectly on creation and edition of the record.
but issue is whenever checkbox is true and i am changing the value of contact lookup filed then Process builder not updating the particular contact's record on the case object.

Checknox name. "Copy info from Contact"

"Please help me out with the solution"

Formula:

```
AND(
    OR(
       [Case].Contact_same_on_Job_Site__c,
        AND(
             PRIORVALUE([Case].ContactId) <> [Case].ContactId,
             [Case].Contact_same_on_Job_Site__c
        )
    ),
    OR(
        [Case].RecordType.Name= 'Customer Request', 
        [Case].RecordType.Name= 'Advanced Field Request'
    )
)
```

Comment: As per req "When checkbox is true and contact look up record is changed then all the fields value should change

Comment: What you're saying and what your formula is showing are different. What is the "contact_same_on_Job_Site__c" field and how does it play into this? Your request talks about a "copy info from contact" field that doesn't seem to exist within your formula. Are you needing to remove the "contact_same_on_job_site__c" field or keep it?

Comment: actually check box API Name..

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write it:

```
AND(
    [Case].Contact_same_on_Job_Site__c,
    NOT(ISBLANK([Case].ContactId))
    OR(
        ISCHANGED([Case].ContactId),
        ISNEW()
    ),
    CONTAINS('Advanced Field Request,Customer Request', [Case].RecordType.Name)
)
```